# Find column in source sheet and copy data from the column and paste in destination sheet

Tags: search, google-sheets, copy, cell, columnheader

I have to search column heading in a sheet1 in the same workbook and copy cells from it to Sheet2 column AZ if sheet1's A column and Sheet2's C column match.

The following Macro copies addresses very good. I have to copy value in them. But if I change to value at the end of the line indicated below macro, it does not work. your help will be appreciated.

```
 Sub SearchCopy()

Dim Dic As Object, key As Variant, oCell As Range, i&
Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet


Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Set w1 = Workbooks("CSheet.xlsx").Sheets("stock")
Set w2 = Workbooks("alcSheet.xlsx").Sheets("Sale")

i = w1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

Dim aCell As Range
Dim colname As String
Dim col As Long
'Dim mYvalue As Long
Dim myNum As String

With w1

    Set aCell = .Range("A1:AZ1").Find(What:="customer", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        col = aCell.Column
        colname = Split(.Cells(, col).address, "$")(1)
    End If

    For Each oCell In w1.Range("B2:B" & i)
    If Not Dic.Exists(oCell.Value) Then
 ' If I change to value at the end of the line below, it does not work.
       mYvalue = Cells(oCell.Row, colname).address

        Dic.Add oCell.Value, mYvalue
    End If
Next
End With
i = w2.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

For Each oCell In w2.Range("A2:A" & i)
    For Each key In Dic
        If oCell.Value = key Then

            oCell.Offset(, 39).Value = Dic(key)

        End If
    Next
Next

 End Sub
```

Comment: any reason why not use HLOOKUP / VLOOKUP fx?

Comment: I have to use multiple sheets with same column head in different places. I have no choice. I tried this method. I could copy only addresses, not values. Now, I discovered what happened. I found what I missed. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

```
     Sub SearchCopy()

      Dim Dic As Object, key As Variant, oCell As Range, i&
      Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet


      Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

      Set w1 = Workbooks("CSheet.xlsx").Sheets("stock")
      Set w2 = Workbooks("alcSheet.xlsx").Sheets("Sale")

      i = w1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

     Dim aCell As Range
     Dim colname As String
     Dim col As Long
       Dim mYvalue As range
       Dim myNum As String

       With w1

       Set aCell = .Range("A1:AZ1").Find(What:="customer", LookIn:=xlValues, 
     LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
    col = aCell.Column
    colname = Split(.Cells(, col).address, "$")(1)
End If

For Each oCell In w1.Range("B2:B" & i)
If Not Dic.Exists(oCell.Value) Then
      ' If I change to value at the end of the line below, it did not work. Now, I specified sheet, and it works
   set mYvalue = w1.Cells(oCell.Row, colname)

    Dic.Add oCell.Value, mYvalue.value
End If
      Next
      End With
      i = w2.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

         For Each oCell In w2.Range("A2:A" & i)
For Each key In Dic
    If oCell.Value = key Then

        oCell.Offset(, 52).Value = Dic(key)

    End If
          Next
            Next

      End Sub
```